# Android - fragment to activity and back

Tags: android, android-fragments

In Android, when we replace a container view with a new fragment, we can use replace() and addToBackStack( ), so on pressing back button we goto previous fragment.

But what if the following occurs :

Activity1 (fragment1 -> fragment2 [calls startActivity for Activity2]) -> Activity2

Within Activity1, I can press back button to go from fragment2 to fragment1. But when fragment2 starts another activity, on pressing back button from Activity2, it takes me to fragment1 in Activity1. How can I make back button press from Activity2 come back to fragment2 in Activity1 ?

Code :

```
// In Activity1 - starts with a ListFragment
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, ListFragment.newInstance(0))
            .commit();
}

// In Activity1 , each item in list replaces the container view 
// with new fragment
@Override
public void onItemSelected(int position) {

    if(position == 0) {

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, Example1_Fragment.newInstance(0))
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

    }
   ....
 }

 // In Example1_Fragment

public class Example1_Fragment extends Fragment {

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example1_fragment, container, false);

    Button btnIntent = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnIntent);
    btnIntent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("com.android.test2.app.example1_action");
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

// this is why I want to come back to Example1_Fragment - 
// the activity I start has to send a result back to
// the Example1_Fragment, but on back button, it takes me
// back to the ListFragment, and I cannot take any UI
// action (change to UI) in Example1_Fragment, as the
// ListFragment gets displayed - the onActivityResult of
// Example1_Fragment does get called

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

             // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not replace Fragment1 in onResume() callback, this method will always be called when you come back to activity1, please do it in onCreate() callback.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. So I presume when I move the code onCreate(), on back button, nothing happens in terms of UI in Activity1, so my fragment2 stays. Is that correct ?

Comment: Do you mean that when you come back to activity1, fragment2 shows currently?

Comment: With your suggestion, it works fine, I moved the code to onCreate. It doesn't work when in onResume.

Comment: OK. I think you should read the documentation about the lifecycle of activity, http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html. This documentation will help you more.

Answer (score -1):

You can manually set the back pressed calls inside of this method in your Second Activity.  So that when you press back, you can find fragment 2 by its tag and add it back.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(this, firstActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            FragmentTwo fragmentTwo = manager.findFragmentByTag("fragmentTwoTag");
            manager.beginTransaction.replace(fragmentOne, fragmentTwo).addToBackStack(null).commit();


    }
```